# Why am I getting "Could not find acceptable representation" error on this API call?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I am trying to map a json response similar to this to a POJO on a rest template exchange:

```
{
    "Is Active": false,
    "Details": {
        "Base Data": {
            "Document{{tags=Document{{application=myApp}}, dimensions=Document{{}}}}": 2911
        },
        "Events Previous": {
        },
        "Name": "Value" 
        "Cumulative Data": {
            "Document{{tags=Document{{application=myApp}}, dimensions=Document{{}}}}": 1000
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my POJOs that I have defined.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ApiResponse implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("Details")
    private Details details;

    @JsonProperty("Is Active")
    private boolean isActive;
    
    //Getters and Setters

}
```

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Details implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("Base Data")
    private Data gauge;

    @JsonProperty("Cumulative Data")
    private Data cumulativeData;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("Document{{tags=Document{{application=myApp}}, dimensions=Document{{}}}}")
    private int data;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

I have ignored all the properties that I do not need for my purposes. When I make the rest call, I receive an exception, attached below

```
ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> apiResponse= restTemplate.getForEntity(url, ApiResponse.class);
```

```
406 Not Acceptable: [{"message":"Could not find acceptable representation","timestamp":1694372115059,"type":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException","details":{},"validationMessages":[]}]
```

How can I resolve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried modelling `Events Previous` and `Name` as well?

Comment: Yes I have. But that does not work either. Strange thing is I tried to exchange with ```restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class)``` as well, which threw the same error. Only ```restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class)``` seems to be working